# How to split char pointer array into two new char pointer array with delimiters?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I currently have an char *command[SIZE] array in main that is filled by taking in user input. An example of what can be filled in is, {"ls", "-1", "|" "sort"}. I want to take in this as a parameter for a function and split it in two arrays (char *command1[SIZE], char *command2[SIZE]) using the delimiter "|". So char *command1[SIZE] contains {"ls", and "-l"}, and char *command2[SIZE] contains {"sort"}. Command1 and command2 should not contain the delimiter.

Here is part of my code below...

**
void executePipeCommand(char *command) {

```
  char *command1[SIZE];
  char *command2[SIZE];


 //split command array between the delimiter for further processing. (the delimiter 
   is not needed in the two new array)
```

}

int main(void) {

```
  char *command[SIZE];

  //take in user input...

  executePipeCommand(command);
```

}

**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for any number of split tokens, and you can pick a split token.

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> SplitCommands(const std::vector<std::string>& commands, const std::string& split_token)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> ret;
    if (! commands.empty())
    {
        ret.push_back(std::vector<std::string>());
        for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator it = commands.begin(), end_it = commands.end(); it != end_it; ++it)
        {
            if (*it == split_token)
            {
                ret.push_back(std::vector<std::string>());
            }
            else
            {
                ret.back().push_back(*it);
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

To convert to required format

```
std::vector<std::string> commands;
char ** commands_unix;
commands_unix = new char*[commands.size() + 1]; // execvp requires last pointer to be null
commands_unix[commands.size()] = NULL;
for (std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator begin_it = commands.begin(), it = begin_it, end_it = commands.end(); it != end_it; ++it)
{
    commands_unix[it - begin_it] = new char[it->size() + 1]; // +1 for null terminator
    strcpy(commands_unix[it - begin_it], it->c_str());
}


// code to delete (I don't know when you should delete it as I've never used execvp)
for (size_t i = 0; i < commands_unix_size; i++)
{
    delete[] commands_unix[i];
}
delete[] commands_unix;
```

Comment: Is there a way that I can implement it with the arrays I was originally using because I need the data in those array so I can call the unix command execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]), which takes in those parameters.